# Why does this Alexa custom skill's Lambda in Nodejs doesnt work (Alexa doesnt speak, times out)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have to publish an MQTT message to my mqtt broker on an Intent match, following is the code that does not work as expected.

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt-async');

function sendMQTTMessage(json)
{
    if(!client || !client.connected)
    {
        console.log('found mqtt client to be not connected');
        if(client)client.end();

        var options = {
        username: 'uname',
        password: 'pass',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        clean: true
        };

        client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://ip:8883',options);
        client.on('connect', () => {
            client.publish('alexaIntentMatch', JSON.stringify(json));
            console.log('sent');
        });
    }
    else//publish now
    {
        client.publish('alexaIntentMatch', JSON.stringify(json));
        console.log('sent');
    }
}
const ItineraryIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'itinerary';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        var res = {'intentName':'ITENARY'};
        sendMQTTMessage(res);
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak('You asked for ITENARY').getResponse();}
};
```

what happens is, Alexa **doesnt speak** (can see in cloudwatch that the request timesout after 8 odd seconds) while the message is successfully sent to mqtt broker.

```
Task timed out after 8.01 seconds
```

While this piece of code works just fine,

```
const ItineraryIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
        && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'itinerary';
},
handle(handlerInput) {let userID = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.userId;
    let client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://ip:8883',{
    username: 'uname',
    password: 'pass',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    clean: true
    });
    client.on('connect', () => {
        var res = {'intentName':'ITENARY'};
        client.publish('alexaIntentMatch', JSON.stringify(res));
        console.log('worked');
        client.end();
    });
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak("Today's itinerary is displayed on your TV.").getResponse();}};
```

Is there anything silly that has been missed here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `async` `await`:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt-async');

async function sendMQTTMessage(json)
{
    if(!client || !client.connected)
    {
        console.log('found mqtt client to be not connected');
        if(client)client.end();

        var options = {
        username: 'uname',
        password: 'pass',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        clean: true
        };

        client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://ip:8883',options);
        client.on('connect', () => {
            await client.publish('alexaIntentMatch', JSON.stringify(json));
            console.log('sent');
        });
    }
    else//publish now
    {
        await client.publish('alexaIntentMatch', JSON.stringify(json));
        console.log('sent');
    }
}
const ItineraryIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'itinerary';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        var res = {'intentName':'ITENARY'};
        await sendMQTTMessage(res);
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak('You asked for ITENARY').getResponse();}
};
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, I have already tried similar approaches, neither work. Just the one mentioned above works, cant seem to figure out why

Comment: It's because JS will not wait for Promise(connecting to `mqtt`) to finish and it will directly call the Alexa's `handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak` request. So by adding `async` `await` everywhere, you say JS to finish this Promise and then only proceed to next instruction.

Comment: You can learn how JS sync, async works here - https://medium.com/better-programming/is-javascript-synchronous-or-asynchronous-what-the-hell-is-a-promise-7aa9dd8f3bfb

Comment: understood, but how does that make alexa to not speak the text sent to it in handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak, its a static text

Comment: If it's static and doesn't relate to Promise, then it should work. Try removing all of your Promise code and use vanilla request like this https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-hello-world/blob/master/lambda/custom/index.js#L18 . From line 18 to 30.